Use spring-cloud-circuitbreaker in a non spring boot project
I'd like to use spring-cloud-circuitbreaker in a non spring(boot/mvc) project...
Is it possible? I haven't found anything related to it...
Can someone helpe me?
I searched about the situation but haven't found something about it.
